# Handling Errors with Esri Leaflet Dynamic Map Layers

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I have an application that is using ESRI for leaflet to pull in MapServices.  I can successfully pull in map services and render in my application.  However, sometimes the map services return an error (400, 500, etc).  When this occurs I can no longer click on other data I am showing on the map (geojson data coming from a MongoDB).  Is there a way to handle these errors so they do not interfere with the user experience?

Comment: which type of layer are you creating (feature, tiled, dynamic, etc)? Can you share a simple code snippet which demonstrates how you're building the layer from geojson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the services are returning errors intermittently when you attempt to load them, my suggestions in the issue below should be helpful.

https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/705

if something else is going on, please provide a little more info (particularly im interested in what type of services you're loading and what specific types of requests are failing.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution for the services that have MetaData as a child resource.  Any ideas on how to handle services that do not?  An example of such a service is http://www.geocommunicator.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/PLSS/MapServer

Comment: This is the error I am getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.geocommunicator.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/PLSS/MapServer/?f=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: we don't look for a metadata child resource, we make an 'f=json' request to the service itself: http://jsbin.com/sizujicera/edit?html,output

Comment: that's because your web server doesn't support CORS.  see my jsbin for a working example.

Comment: Ahh, some of the services do support CORS, some do not.  Working perfectly now, thanks for the help!

Comment: ArcGIS Server 10.1 and above supports CORS out of the box, previously it was up to the web server administrator: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37406/discussion-between-shane-and-john-gravois).